# link to send email from android app in xml string resource

Tags: android, xml, string, email, contacts

[image: ScreenShot]

I have a "Contact Us" Activity in my android application. On clicking the contact number, I want to copy the contact number to the dialler so that the user can dial that number. Similarly, on clicking the email, I want the user to go to his mail with that email address copied to the "sendto" field. Is it possible statically by putting that contact number and email in the strings.xml resource file? I have tried this:-

```
<string name="call_us">Call us at <a href="+91 1234567890">+91 1234567890</a></string>
<string name="email_us">Email us at <a href="abc@gmail.com">abc@gmail.com</a></string>
```

But, it is not working.

```
<LinearLayout
    style="@style/StyleHorizontalLinearLayout">

    <ImageView
        style="@style/StyleSmallIcon"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_call"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:text="@string/call_us"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: How did you make this ui, could you add the related code to your question? In general I would use html to make clickable links in such an activity.

Comment: @rekire I have added the code. Everything, I want to do statically through layouts and resources. Is it possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I use for such cases this code:

```java
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.call_us)));
tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

The last line does the clicking logic for you. So when you click that link the magic happens.

You also need to add a schema to the urls:

```
<string name="call_us">Call us at <a href="tel:+911234567890">+91 1234567890</a></string>
<string name="email_us">Email us at <a href="mailto:abc@gmail.com">abc@gmail.com</a></string>
```

With that `tel:` and `mailto:` your links will work.

Comment: textViewEmailUs = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view_email_us);
        textViewEmailUs.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.email_us)));
        textViewEmailUs.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());


<string name="email_us"><a href="abc@gmail.com">abc@gmail.com</a></string>



Not Working : (
Even the hyperlink went away.

Comment: Thanks a lot, It's not only working. It's running.....;)
Once again, thanks a lot.

Comment: Adding the url in strings.xml as shown here + adding `android:autoLink="email"` in the textview worked for me