# android:autoLink is not working in ButtonView in Android?

Tags: android, xml, android-button, autolink

I have used autolink in ButtonView like below,

```
 <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/email"
            android:autoLink="email"
            />
```

if I used string like below I am able to go to email,

```
<string name="mail"><a href = "abc@gmail.com">abc@gmail.com</a></string>
```

But If I do like below, not happening,

```
<string name="mail"><a href = "abc@gmail.com">Send Mail</a></string>
```

That is the problemmm...
but nothing happened on clicking button...
When I used autolink for textView worked perfectly.. But why not working for Button???Thanks in advance

Comment: please share java code

Comment: i answered below...just try that method

Comment: because `abc@gmail.com` this is not a valid link

Comment: @just that is reference only...not actual email

Comment: but that reference should be valid link ...not should be email address

Comment: @Wini acutal email used in my app is valid only...thats not a problem

Comment: @Wini do you understood my pbm??

Comment: @Wini if I used text instead of email ,that time only redirection not working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem when doing like below,

```
mailRedirectButton.setAutoLinkMask(0);
String content="<a href =mailto:abc@gmail.com>Send</a>";
        mailRedirectButton.setText(Html.fromHtml(content));
        mailRedirectButton.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Referred here https://stackoverflow.com/a/33709981/12273964

Thank you for everyone who tried to help me..

Answer (score 0):

Hai Sandhiya you can use Linkify class to achieve your needs. try that one